# Replace NaN's in an array in a specific way

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of the form (simplified here): `[1,NaN,NaN,7,NaN,27]`. I want to replace the `NaN's` with values equally spaced between the known values, so the above array would become `[1,3,5,7,17,27]`. Is there a fast way to do this (without using some for loops)? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Pandas dataframe.interpolate() function is basically used to fill NA values in the dataframe or series

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = [ 1, np.NaN, np.NaN, 7, np.NaN, 27]
//converting array in series 
print(pd.Series(arr).interpolate(method = 'linear', limit_direction = 'forward'))
```

**Parameters**
**method = 'linear'**: Ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced.
**limit_direction :** {‘forward’, ‘backward’, ‘both’}, default ‘forward’
If limit is specified, consecutive NaNs will be filled in this direction.
**limit :** int, optional
Maximum number of consecutive NaNs to fill. Must be greater than 0.

```
print(pd.Series(arr).interpolate(method = 'linear', limit_direction = 'forward', limit = 1))
#5 won't  get printed
print(pd.Series(arr).interpolate(method = 'linear', limit_direction = 'backward', limit = 1))
#3 won't get printed
```

You can try different variations based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If possible use `pandas` create `Series` and then use [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = [1,np.NaN,np.NaN,7,np.NaN,27]

print (pd.Series(arr).interpolate().values)
[ 1.  3.  5.  7. 17. 27.]
```